# Jacoco code coverage in Android is 0 percent (with Java 8)

Tags: java, android, gradle, code-coverage, jacoco

I am having issues with calculating code coverage on Android, gradle 2.14.1 with Java 8.

I've added testCoverageEnabled to my apps build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

android {
    debug {
        testCoverageEnabled true
    }
}
```

I can execute Jacoco with **./gradlew createDebugCoverageReport**.

I get my coverage report (both html & .exec) but the coverage is always 0 percent. Anyone has encountered this and solved it?

Comment: I am facing same problem raised a question about the same
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42451660/android-jacoco-coverage-shows-0-with-gradle-however-there-are-95-tests-coverin/42457455#42457455

Comment: In my case it was device specific problem. I was running it on Samsung Tab4 and coverage was showing as 0%. When I ran the same on Emulator and on a different device (Asus Zenpad) then it shows correct coverage report

Comment: Hmm I want to calculate it for unit tests.

Comment: Did you try this? It worked for me with Unit tests as well
https://medium.com/@rafael_toledo/setting-up-an-unified-coverage-report-in-android-with-jacoco-robolectric-and-espresso-ffe239aaf3fa#.sbd6apm4i