# android jacoco coverage shows 0% with gradle however there are 95% tests covering code

Tags: android, gradle, jacoco

I'm trying to get jacoco create a code coverage report for my android test project.

Gradle version `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'`

I have the following in build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.7.1.201405082137"
}

android {
    buildTypes {
        release {
        }
        debug {
            testCoverageEnabled true
        }
    }
}
```

It shows report as below image
[image]

There is almost 95% of the code coverage (When I ran the same report in 2015 it showed the report as 95%). Nothing much changed in the code and the test folders ever since then. So ideally it should show coverage as something like this

[image]

I tried running report with both JDK7 & 8 but same result. Also tried changing to latest versions of JaCoCo, but still same result.

Any ideas why the report is shown as 0% coverage? While running the Gradle task it runs my tests in androidTest folder successfully though.
[image]

[Facing same issue as mentioned in this question - This question is unanswered yet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35337661/0-code-coverage-on-espresso-tests-with-jacoco-and-gradle/35337997)

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem - see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: This is the repo
https://github.com/pwittchen/prefser/tree/master/library
It need not be down voted for the Repo. As this issue is seen with the Gradle versions provided with all code bases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generation of coverage for [your project](https://github.com/pwittchen/prefser) using command

```
./gradlew clean createDebugCoverageReport
```

works just fine:

[image: report]

The only thing that I changed - is `compileSdkVersion` from `23` to `25` and `buildToolsVersion` from `23.0.1` to `25.0.2`, because this is the versions that I have.

Comment: What is the AndroidStudio version & Java version that you are using?

Comment: @Guna I believe that usage of latest released versions is a very good practice and that's what I do, so as of today: Android Studio 2.2.3, Oracle JDK 8u121, on Linux

Comment: I am running it on Samsung Tab 4. What is the device you ran it on?

Comment: @Guna Nexus 5 in emulator

Comment: Device was the problem. I was running it on Samsung Tab 4 and it showed 0% Coverage. When I ran the same on Emulator and on a different device (Asus Zenpad) then it shows correct coverage report.

Comment: @Guna Thanks, Solution worked for me.I was this issue from last 2 days.

Comment: @RohitBandil Glad it helped!

Answer (score 11):

I had the exact same problem. But using the comment from Guna (27 Feb 2017), it seems that the problem is caused by running the coverage tests on some Samsung devices.

- On **some newer Samsung devices**, when you run the Jacoco gradle task `createDebugCoverageReport` or `createDebugAndroidTestCoverageReport`, it will run the unit tests, but show **0% coverage**.
- But on a **Google Nexus 5 or most emulators**, when you run the same Jacoco task, it will **work fine** and show the correct coverage. Older Samsung devices also work well.

It's very odd.

Also remember to ensure that all your tests pass first. This is another limitation of Jacoco, because even if one small test fails in your whole suite, it will not generate a test coverage report. Another note: Your app may be [automatically uninstalled when the coverage report is generated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58664370/how-do-i-stop-gradle-instrumented-test-runs-from-uninstalling-the-app). Unknown reason why - you'll just have to reinstall it.

**Update, 11 October 2018:** There is a way to generate a coverage report even if an individual test fails. Use this in your app/build.gradle (from [here](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/jacoco/eMFn90cdrg8/discussion)):

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        testCoverageEnabled = true
    }
}

project.gradle.taskGraph.whenReady {
    connectedDebugAndroidTest {
        ignoreFailures = true
    }
}
```

Automated build scripts may need to use the `"--continue"` flag, to ensure a unit test failure will continue the gradle task; something like this:

```
./gradlew createDebugCoverageReport --continue
```

Further info, see also:

- https://web.archive.org/web/20171210224809/http://blog.wittchen.biz.pl/test-coverage-report-for-android-application (also view the user comments)
- http://wittchen.io/posts/test-coverage-in-android-applications/ (same article as above, but without the user comments)
- [Ignore Gradle Build Failure and continue build script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28998372)
- http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2014/12/gradle-goodness-continue-build-even.html

Comment: 'Also remember to ensure that all your tests pass first'. That line saved me. Thanks for your post.

Comment: Good old samsung annoying devs since 2009. Of course it works perfectly on the Nexus 5.